# maven-bundle-plugin doesn't include Import-Package

Tags: java, maven

I have parent pom where my child pom locates like a module.

In my child bundle's pom I have something like that

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>...</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            <Bundle-Description>...</Bundle-Description>
                            <Bundle-Activator>...</Bundle-Activator>
                            <Import-Package>
                                oracle.sql,
                                oracle.jdbc,
                                javax.jws,
                                javax.jws.soap,
                                javax.xml.bind,
                                javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                                javax.xml.namespace,
                                javax.xml.ws,
                                *
                            </Import-Package>
                            <Export-Package>
                            </Export-Package>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But in the Manifest I get something like that

```
javax.jws,
javax.jws.soap,
javax.xml.bind,
javax.xml.bind.annotation,
javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,
javax.xml.datatype,
javax.xml.namespace
```

but I haven't got my oracle.sql and oracle.jdbc.

It happens when I make `mvn clean install` from the parent folder. If I make `mvn clean install` in the directory where my child pom locates, everything OK. But question happened after I saw that Jenkin`s build didn't include **oracle's** packages.

There is interesting in that case, I have other modules which include *oracle's** packages too and after building their manifest has it.

Comment: Where have you defined oracle jdbc dependency?

Comment: I didn't define anywhere. I've just needed to include that package into my jar imported Package. I haven't it in my dependency also as in other modules

Comment: First include the oracle jdbc dependency in dependencies section of pom.xml.

Comment: I thought the same, but if search any oracle.sql through my poms (parent or child) I wouldn't find any dependency with that. Only imports in **<Import-Package>**. In my other module's manifest I get `Import-Package: org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)",org.apache.cxf.transport.com
 mon.gzip;version="[3,4)",org.springframework.util;version="[3.2,4)",
 com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json;version="[2.6,3)",com.g
 oogle.code.yanf4j.util,com.google.common.base;version="[18.0,19)",com.g
 oogle.common.io;version="[18.0,19)",com.lowagie.text,` **oracle.sql,oracle.jdbc** ,`.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. 
I have that plugin inside  but Jenkins creates bundles without any Profile so, it generated without my Import-Package.

It looks like

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>My-Own-Profile</id>
            <build>
             <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>...</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Description>...</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-Activator>...</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>
                            oracle.sql,
                            oracle.jdbc,
                            javax.jws,
                            javax.jws.soap,
                            javax.xml.bind,
                            javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                            javax.xml.namespace,
                            javax.xml.ws,
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

But I should make it like

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>My-Own-Profile</id>
            <build>
             <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  **SOME PLUGIN FOR THAT PROFILE**
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
           <build>
             <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>...</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Description>...</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-Activator>...</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Import-Package>
                            oracle.sql,
                            oracle.jdbc,
                            javax.jws,
                            javax.jws.soap,
                            javax.xml.bind,
                            javax.xml.bind.annotation,
                            javax.xml.namespace,
                            javax.xml.ws,
                            *
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following dependency in pom.xml in dependencies section.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that you can check.

Comment: As I said, I haven't any dependency in every module which consists *.oracle* in it but I have imported oracle.jdbc in Imported-Package. I don't know how. And I need that. I have not even had that in parent pom.

Comment: If you are using database connectivity, you require this jar file. Now you have two options. First remove the packages oracle.sql, oracle.jdbc and check whether OSGI bundle is able to load to run the application. If application is running fine, it means these packages are nor required. Second option is check any other project how are you connecting database using these packages. Are you using Adobe CQ/AEM ?

Comment: I use apache-servicemix where I add as a bundle that oracle.jar. My connection to DAO creates with `<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">` where 1 of parameters is `<entry key="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.OracleDictionary" />`  And that class I get from `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>` in each module

Comment: @Dred, You mentioned that "I use apache-servicemix where I add as a bundle that oracle.jar". You have to put the dependency for that oracle.jar in pom.xml.

Comment: I found my error. I have that plugin inside <profile> but Jenkins creates bundles without any Profile so, it generated without my Import-Package.